# java - Shiro + Spring MVC, in memory users xml

Tags: java, xml, spring, shiro

I want to test Apache Shiro integrated with Spring MVC. Before adding a Realm, I want to test this with users in memory in the way that shiro.ini define it. I cannot find enough information about Spring+Shiro.

I would like to add users in applicationConfig.xml as shiro.ini does it:

```
[users]
root = secret, admin
myname = 0000, admin
guest = guest, guest
presidentskroob = 12345, president
darkhelmet = ludicrousspeed, darklord, schwartz
lonestarr = vespa, goodguy, schwartz
```

But in Apache Shiro support [page](http://shiro.apache.org/spring.html) I cannot find how to do this:

```
<bean id="shiroFilter" class="org.apache.shiro.spring.web.ShiroFilterFactoryBean">
    <property name="securityManager" ref="securityManager"/>
    <!-- override these for application-specific URLs if you like:-->
    <property name="loginUrl" value="/login"/>
    <property name="successUrl" value="/home.jsp"/>
    <property name="unauthorizedUrl" value="/unauthorized.jsp"/>
    <!-- The 'filters' property is not necessary since any declared javax.servlet.Filter bean  -->
    <!-- defined will be automatically acquired and available via its beanName in chain        -->
    <!-- definitions, but you can perform instance overrides or name aliases here if you like: -->
    <!-- <property name="filters">
        <util:map>
            <entry key="anAlias" value-ref="someFilter"/>
        </util:map>
    </property> -->
    <property name="filterChainDefinitions">
        <value>
            # some example chain definitions:
            /admin/** = authc, roles[admin]
            /docs/** = authc, perms[document:read]
            /** = authc
            # more URL-to-FilterChain definitions here
        </value>
    </property>
</bean>

<bean id="securityManager" class="org.apache.shiro.web.mgt.DefaultWebSecurityManager"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

Apache Shiro define in memory users in a simple way at the shiro.ini file. But in spring implementation is necesary to define a Realm that which will store the users.

For this case (spring xml users) there are three Realms capable to do this:

- [TextConfigurationRealm](https://shiro.apache.org/static/1.2.2/apidocs/org/apache/shiro/realm/text/TextConfigurationRealm.html) for simple text based users and roles.
- [PropertiesRealm](https://shiro.apache.org/static/1.2.1/apidocs/org/apache/shiro/realm/text/PropertiesRealm.html) for a specified .properties file with users and roles.
- [IniRealm](https://shiro.apache.org/static/1.2.2/apidocs/org/apache/shiro/realm/text/IniRealm.html) to use the shiro.ini [users] and [roles].

First configure Shiro Beans:

```
<!-- Optionally for defining form login parameters. Could be excluded -->
<bean id="formAuthenticationFilter" class="org.apache.shiro.web.filter.authc.FormAuthenticationFilter">
    <property name="usernameParam" value="username"/>
    <property name="passwordParam" value="password"/>
    <property name="rememberMeParam" value="rememberMe"/>
    <property name="failureKeyAttribute" value="shiroLoginFailure"/>
    <property name="loginUrl" value="/login.jsp"/>
</bean>

<!-- Required Shiro Bean -->
<bean id="shiroFilter" class="org.apache.shiro.spring.web.ShiroFilterFactoryBean">
    <property name="securityManager" ref="securityManager"/>
    <!-- override these for application-specific URLs if you like:-->
    <property name="loginUrl" value="/login.jsp"/>
    <property name="successUrl" value="/success.jsp"/>
    <property name="unauthorizedUrl" value="/unauthorized.jsp"/>
    <!-- The 'filters' property is not necessary since any declared javax.servlet.Filter bean  -->
    <!-- defined will be automatically acquired and available via its beanName in chain        -->
    <!-- definitions, but you can perform instance overrides or name aliases here if you like: -->
    <property name="filters">
        <util:map>
            <!--declare form authc filter if neccesary-->
            <entry key="authc" value-ref="formAuthenticationFilter"/>
        </util:map>
    </property>
    <property name="filterChainDefinitions">
        <value>
            # some example chain definitions:
            /public/** = anon
            /admin/** = authc, roles[admin]
            /docs/** = authc, perms[document:read]
            /logout = logout
            /** = authc
            # more URL-to-FilterChain definitions here
        </value>
    </property>
</bean>

<bean id="securityManager" class="org.apache.shiro.web.mgt.DefaultWebSecurityManager" >
    <property name="realm" ref="myRealm"/>
</bean>

<bean id="myRealm" class="org.apache.shiro.realm.text... (see below)
```

SecurityManager beans defines the realm or realms that we will create, it can be JdbcRealm, TextRealm, LdapReaml, etc. For more information [see this](http://shiro.apache.org/spring.html).

**TextConfigurationRealm**: Take a look at **init-method="processDefinitions"** because if we don't declare this, spring will never load the users nor roles defined.

```
<bean id="myRealm" class="org.apache.shiro.realm.text.TextConfigurationRealm" init-method="processDefinitions">
    <property name="userDefinitions">
        <value>
            wlparrar = passw0rd, admin
            jsmith = jsmithsPassword, manager, engineer, employee
            abrown = abrownsPassword, qa, employee
            djones = djonesPassword, qa, contractor
            guest = guestPassword
        </value>
    </property>
    <property name="roleDefinitions">
        <value>
            admin = *
            schwartz = lightsaber:*
            goodguy = winnebago:drive:eagle5
        </value>
    </property>
</bean>
```

**PropertiesRealm:** people say this is and very old realm. I tried to test it but I cannot do it. However I found how to declare it. Properties file should be in resources path to be called with **classpath:shiro-users.properties**:

```
<bean id="propertiesRealm" class="org.apache.shiro.realm.text.PropertiesRealm">
    <!--Althought default classpath is classpath:shiro-users.properties-->
    <property name="resourcePath" value="classpath:shiro-users.properties"/>
</bean>
```

**IniRealm:** this should be in resources path to be called with classpath:shiro.ini. The [common way](https://github.com/sangeeth/apache-shiro-samples/blob/master/simple-rbac/src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/applicationContext.xml) to declare this realm doesn't worked for me, but finally I found a [way](http://shiro-user.582556.n2.nabble.com/use-PropertiesRealm-td5866531.html) that worked perfectly:

```
<bean id="myRealm" class="org.apache.shiro.realm.text.IniRealm">
    <constructor-arg type="java.lang.String" value="classpath:shiro.ini"/> 
</bean>
```